# jQuery click individual elements on time interval

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using JQVMap to render a world map on a page. I need to automatically click an individual map region every 10 seconds in a particular sequence. Here is my javascript so far:

```
//get each region in the sequence
var asiaID = document.getElementById('jqvmap1_cn'); //China
var americaID = document.getElementById('jqvmap1_ar'); //Argentina
var africaID = document.getElementById('jqvmap1_et'); //Ethiopia
var europeID = document.getElementById('jqvmap1_ru'); //Russia
var eastID = document.getElementById('jqvmap1_pk'); //Pakistan

var regionArray = [asiaID, americaID, africaID, europeID, eastID];
var arrayLength = regionArray.length;

//trigger sequence on time interval
setInterval(autoCycle, 10000);

//cycle through each region with click
function autoCycle(){
    //loop through each region
    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++) {
        jQuery(regionArray[i]).trigger('click');
        console.log(regionArray[i]);
    }
}
```

With this code, ALL of the regions in regionArray are clicked simultaneously every 10 seconds. I need them to be clicked individually in sequence, if that makes sense. Will a for() loop not work for this?

Comment: you need to add a delay after each one, instead of clicking them all at 10000 ms

Comment: @bruchowski with your suggestion, would I need to change the setInterval function to 50000 (the total time to cycle through the 5 regions) and then set the delay after each region to 10000? Do you mind providing an example to help me understand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use this logic instead:

```
var i = 0;
setInterval(function(){autoCycle(i++%arrayLength)}, 10000);

//cycle through each region with click
function autoCycle(i) {
    jQuery(regionArray[i]).trigger('click');   
}
```

Comment: This is running perfectly! Although I'm not familiar with some of the syntax you've used. I'll make sure to look through the jQuery documentation.

Comment: Excellent. I am also learning! Simple yet Elegant. With this question has been answered, I would delete my invalid answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) You don't need getElementByID if you using jquery
2) You may use setTimeout and recursion

```
var regionArray = ['#jqvmap1_cn', '#jqvmap1_ar', '#jqvmap1_et', '#jqvmap1_ru', '#jqvmap1_pk'];
    var arrayLength = regionArray.length;

    function autoCycle(i) {
      if (i < arrayLength) {
        jQuery(regionArray[i]).trigger('click');
        setTimeout(function(){autoCycle(++i);}, 10000);
      }
    }

    autoCycle(0);
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps clean up my code a lot. I'm still somewhat unfamiliar with all of the cool jQuery syntax. The full code in your answer only clicks the first element in the array every 10 seconds from what I can see.

Comment: @JesseDillman See updated code. Problem was in i++ (details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/26k41698(v=vs.94).aspx)